# How to call defined values as a loop in shell

Tags: linux, shell

I am facing a problem here. I would like to make a loop with the defined values.

```
list="-50..50"

for i in {$list}
  do ...
```

It is executing only single string as

```
for i in -50..50
  do ...
```

My desire execution should be

```
for i in {-50..50}
  do ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see you cant use variables in `bash`'s brace expansion, use `seq` i.e sequence program instead like this:

```
$ low=10
$ high=20
$ for i in {low..high};do #treated as string
> echo $i
> done
{low..high}
$ for i in {$low..$high};do echo $i; done #values substituted but no brace expansion done by bash
{10..20}
$
$ for i in $(seq $low $high);do echo $i; done
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
$
```